# Using concrete type with Angular's Httpclient

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I am using Angular's `Httpclient` to retrieve data from the server. So far I am calling `get<MyModelInterface>`, so that Json gets mapped directly into an object.

However, I would like to be able to call functions on the returned object, for example `size()`. As such I was thinking I would like to pass a concrete type as type parameter to `get()`, so that the constructed object would have a type, and I could call its methods.

As of now, I cannot call any method of the returned object, it only holds data.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know `get<MyModelInterface>` from httpClient only returns an Observable of Type . Do you try to use methods on your subscription? eg.
`httpClient.get<MyModelInterface>(something).subscribe(next => do something)`

you can ecplicit cast your value in the subscription:

```
httpClient.get<MyModelInterface>(something).subscribe((next: MyModelInterface) => {next.method()});
```

Hope that answers your question

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually casting is not necessary, but the problem is that the returned object doesn't have any implementation of the methods. I think under the hood `get` creates an "anonymous" class implementing that interface in the data sense, but without methods, fills it with data, and returns it. Thus the returned object's methods don't exist